# regex optional or zero, the (?) usage confusion

Tags: regex

I want to match these

```
<div class="name">a</div>
<div class="name">b</div>
<div class="name">c</div>
```

so would this be enough : `<div class="name">(.*)<\/div>` ??

or `<div class="name">(.*?)<\/div>` ?

and why this `[<div class="name">](.*)[/div]` doesn't matches?

Comment: `[]` in regex called [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). It would match a single character from the list.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I know that but sorry your comment doesn't answer to my doubts Sir.

Comment: I don't know what your doubt is? Explain your question clearly.

Comment: `[]` means one charcter out of the characters inside.You need to add `+` or `*` so it mactches all of the characters defined inside.But their order can be random.`[/div]` can match `/vid` as well and `v` as well

Comment: `?` after the `*` or `+` would act like a reluctant quantifier. By default `*` and `+` are [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). You need to add `?` after those symbols to force the regex engine to do a non-greedy match(shortest possible match). But `?` after a character or character class or capturing or non-capturing group or escape character would make the previous token or char as optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="name">.*?</div>
```

will probably work best. Using the greedy version `<div class="name">.*</div>` would match multiple `<div>`s as one, e.g. `<div class="name">foo</div><div>bar</div>` would match as a whole.

---

```
[<div class="name">](.*)[/div]
```

does not work because the square braces `[]` denote a character class. So what the pattern does is this:

```
[<div class="name">] // match one of the characters `<div clas="nme>` literally
(.*) // match any character except newline, any number of times
[/div] // match one of the characters `/div` literally
```

---

P.S.: Note that `<div class="name">.*?</div>` won't work with nested `<div>`s.
E.g. in

```
<div class="name">
    <div>foo</div>
</div>
```

it would only match

```
<div class="name">
    <div>foo</div>
```

because the pattern only consumes the string up to the first occurence of `</div>`.